Как компилируется код где я инициализирую переменную её же значением?
Я написал следующий код на c++ и он компилируется:
int main() {
    int x = x;
    return 0;
}

Вопрос, как? Переменная x ведь не существует до собственного объявления. Как тогда я могу использовать её для инициализации её же самой?

Самый генеальный ответ - никак. Она поглащаеться компилятором потому что не используеться. Если убрать все оптимизации то на асме это просто MOV EBX, EBX по сути даже не используеться как переменная, а просто примитивнейшее значение регистра EBX.

Нужно понимать разницу между областью видимости переменной и временем ее жизни.
Область видимости, как вы уже заметили, начинается сразу как компилятор видит ее имя в объявлении, поэтому int x = x; компилируется.
Но время жизни x начинается после завершения иницализации, а попытка прочитать ее до начала времени жизни вызывает неопределенное поведение.

Согласно этой ссылке https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope (из ответа @Uranus), на сколько я понял, int x = x; эквивалентно int x; x = x;. Я не прав? Что, собственно, такое время жизни?

@Усердныйбобёр Не эквивалентно, потому что в первом случае чтение до начала времени жизни, а втором после. Про время жизни: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1 - начинается при завершении инициализации, до начала и после завершения нельзя читать значение, и т.д.

Хотя int x; x = x; не сильно лучше, потому что это чтение неинициализированной переменной.

что тогда делает обращение к переменной до её времени жизни? Читает не выделенную память?

@Усердныйбобёр Зависит от того, выделена ли уже память. :) В случае переменной на стеке она будет уже выделена. В теории, эффект может быть любой. На практике, если оптимизация выключена, скорее всего прочитается рандномное значение. Если оптимизация включена, компилятор может запутаться и сделать что-то странное, а может и не сделать. Если включены санитайзеры, может быть ошибка в рантайме.

Ответ на вопрос нашел в разделе Точка объявления статьи Область видимости на cppreference.com.
Для переменных и других имён, представленных простыми объявлениями, точка объявления находится сразу после объявления имени и перед его инициализатором, если таковой имеется:
int x = 32; // внешний x находится в области видимости
{
    int x = x; // внутренний x находится в области видимости до инициализатора (= x)
               // при этом внутренний x не инициализируется значением внешнего x (32),
               // при этом внутренний x инициализируется собственным (неопределённым)
               // значением
}

